# How to integrate $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^2\ln x}{x^4-x^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, special-functions, contour-integration

First I think it may use the method of contour integration,but I have no idea how to create a contour.And is there some normal method to solve it? $$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^2\ln x}{x^4-x^3+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: The standard way is express the real integral in terms of a contour integral involving $\log(-z)^2$ with +ve x-axis as branch cut over a keyhole contour $C : \infty - i\epsilon \to -i\epsilon \to -\epsilon \to i \epsilon \to \infty + i\epsilon $. $$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2\log x}{x^4 - x^3 + 1}dx = \frac{i}{4\pi}\int_C \frac{z^2\log(-z)^2 dz}{z^4 -z^3 + 1}$$ One then evaluate the contour integral by a partial fraction decomposition of the rational part of its integrand and taking residues.